# Eclipse RCP Application Fails to launch second time

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application that will launch properly after a clean install (right after build).

The issue is that if I try to launch the application a second time the application throws an exception.

I have narrowed the issue down to this file being created after the first run:
~install_dir/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.state

Has anyone run into a similar issue where the .state file prevents the application from being launched anytime after that first run?

I'm hesitant to look at the exception as this does not happen the first time, so I suspect org.eclipse.osgi is more to blame.

The details of the exception are:
"Error creating bean with name 'luceneRawQueryComposer' defined in class path resource [spring/dataaccess/daoCMClient.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'indexUtility' while setting bean property 'indexUtility'; NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Comment: Should also add that if I delete the ~install_dir/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.state file the application will load properly once again.

Comment: which version of Eclipse (RCP) are you using? Which OSGi framework is used? Look some spring framework dependencies are used, maybe also tip us if that is the case and which version there is used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem some months ago as well. I am not sure anymore what caused it, and how I fixed it. I remember that I fixed it after some intensive search in the Web, so the answer is somewhere out there ;-)
Some hints: Do you have a generated or an own config.ini file? Because in the back of my head I think I remember that using the generated config instead of the own one, solved the issue.

Hope this helpd...